# getElementsByClassName issue

Tags: javascript, html

i'm currently having issue with the getElementsByClassName property. I have a show and hide function which displays a button when you hover over the product [click here](http://iamnatesmithen.com/bodyworks/prp) I have enabled this function using the getElementById property, however due to the fact i want to duplicates of this function using a class is better practice. Is the code below the correct way to address this problem using the ClassName JS function?

Also i've been reading getElementsByClassName is not supported in IE8 is this true and is there a way to work around this?

```
  <script>    
  function show(viewProductBtn){
document.getElementByClassName(viewProductBtn).style.visibility = "visible";
}

function hide(viewProductBtn) {
document.getElementByClassName(viewProductBtn).style.visibility = "hidden";
}
</script>

<!--HTML-->
<div class="product-shot-bg" onMouseOver="show('viewProductBtn')"      onMouseOut="hide('viewProductBtn')">
        <a href="#" class="viewProductBtn"></a>
```

at present i've switched the my dev site back to getByID to demonstrate how the transition should work..

Comment: Yes IE doesn't support getElementsByClassName. You can get around this by either rolling your own function that walks the dom and grabs all elements with the same class OR you take the easy way and employ some sort of library that already has it implements such as jQuery OR you use id's. Not certain what you mean you want to duplicate the function? You realize that if you copy the function you are just redefining it?

Comment: @scrappedcola added getElementsByClassName in IE9.

Comment: I shouldn't use the word duplicate.. it's more a loops for when i integrate the site into a cms

Answer (score 6):

`getElement`***`s`***`ByClassName`

"Element***s***" in the plural. Meaning, the function returns an array (actually a NodeList), so you need to either loop through the array, or get the first element if you only want that one.

See also `document.querySelector("."+viewProductBtn)` for one element, `document.querySelectorAll("."+viewProductBtn)` for multiple, or consider using IDs and `getElementById`.

Comment: My first approach was to use IDs but i was curious to know whether there is a cleaner way of doing it?

Comment: Can't get much cleaner than IDs. I guess you could use `this.children[0]` if the link is the first child of the div...