# Find a referenceNode in DOM by ClassName

Tags: javascript, dom

I am attempting to do a jquery `.after` in pure JS.

I have the following script that works for the first div where I append by `getElementById` but not the second where I am using `getElementsByClassName`

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5ek2jps4/)

How can I successfully append by using the element's class?

**HTML**

```
<div id="first-div">First Div - found by ID</div>
<br>
<div class="second-div">Second Div - found by ClassName</div>
```

**JS**

```
function insertAfter(referenceNode, newNode) {
    referenceNode.parentNode.insertBefore(newNode, referenceNode.nextSibling);
}

var element1 = document.createElement("div");
element1.className = 'row'
element1.innerHTML = 'Text to append to first div by ID';
var div1 = document.getElementById('first-div');
insertAfter(div1, element1);

var element2 = document.createElement("div");
element2.className = 'row'
element2.innerHTML = 'Text to append to second div by class';
var div2 = document.getElementsByClassName('second-div');
insertAfter(div2, element2);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [getElementsByClassName issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12377734/getelementsbyclassname-issue)

Comment: In addition to using the first item in the returned array from `getElementsByClassName`, you could alternately use `querySelector`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var div2 = document.getElementsByClassName('second-div')[0];
```

getElementsByClassName returns a iterable so you have to say which one [0] for first

Answer (score 0):

`getElementsByClassName` returns all the elements of that class, therefore the correct way is to iterate through each item

```
var element2 = document.createElement("div");
element2.className = 'row'
element2.innerHTML = 'Text to append to second div by class';
var div2 = document.getElementsByClassName("second-div");
for(var i = 0; i < div2.length; i++)
{
   insertAfter(div2.item(i), element2);
}
var div2 = document.getElementsByClassName('second-div');
```